# how does vs code works with power bi (.pbix) for version control?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, powerbi

I want to version control my .pbix file through vs code, but vs code doesn't recognize the file. Is there a way to version control powerbi through vs code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICS, `.pbix` files are binary, you can effectively version control these files inside **text editor**